# Rust duplicated use statements

Tags: rust

Firt of all, I am a total begginner in Rust, I started to use a code analyzer (Mega-Linter) and it made me realize how much I duplicated the same "use" statements in my submodules. Here what my source file tree looks like :

```
src/
  - lib.rs
  - ui/
      - mod.rs
      - ui_mod_1.rs
      - ui_mod_2.rs
```

Then I realized that my ui_mod_1.rs and ui_mod_2.rs had almost the same bunch of "use" statements :

```
// ui_mod_1.rs
use tui::{
    layout::{Alignment, Constraint, Direction, Layout, Rect},
    style::{Color, Modifier, Style},
};

// rest of the file
```

```
// ui_mod_2.rs
use tui::{
    layout::{Alignment, Constraint, Direction, Layout, Rect},
    style::{Color, Modifier, Style},
};

// rest of the file
```

```
// mod.rs
pub mod ui_mod_1;
pub mod ui_mod_2;
```

```
// lib.rs
pub mod ui;
```

The idea behind ui_mod_1.rs and ui_mod_2.rs is to split "ui utilitaries" functions by theme to avoid having a huge source file containing all of them.
A possible solution is to merge the two files, but this is not what I want to do.

What I tried is to move the "use" that the two submodules have in common in the mod.rs or even in the lib.rs like so :

```
// mod.rs
pub use tui::{
    layout::{Alignment, Constraint, Direction, Layout, Rect},
    style::{Color, Modifier, Style},
};

pub mod ui_mod_1;
pub mod ui_mod_2;
```

But this does not work. After some research I still did not find how to do this.
Is there an elegant way to regroup "use" statements for all submodules ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `ui_prelude` module that contains the use statements as `pub use`, and then do just `use ui_prelude::*` in your modules:

```
// ui_prelude.rs
pub use tui::{
    layout::{Alignment, Constraint, Direction, Layout, Rect},
    style::{Color, Modifier, Style},
};
```

```
// ui_mod_1.rs and ui_mod_2.rs
use super::ui_prelude::*;
```

```
// mod.rs
mod ui_prelude.
pub mod ui_mod_1;
pub mod ui_mod_2;
```